# understanding onTrimMemory( int level )

Tags: android, memory-management, android-fragments, android-activity

I recently read this article on *[Managing Your App's Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)*,I strongly suggest to read it if you are an AndroidDev and never did.

There are lots of good practices and one thing I never happen to know about is the [onTrimMemory(int level)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) method called by the system on every Activity/Fragment to notify events on which memory should or could be released.

Here is a quote from that article:

> **Notice that your app receives the onTrimMemory() callback with
>   TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN only when all the UI components of your app
>   process become hidden from the user**. This is distinct from the
>   onStop() callback, which is called when an Activity instance becomes
>   hidden, which occurs even when the user moves to another activity in
>   your app. So although you should implement onStop() to release
>   activity resources such as a network connection or to unregister
>   broadcast receivers, **you usually should not release your UI resources
>   until you receive onTrimMemory(TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN)**. This ensures
>   that if the user navigates back from another activity in your app,
>   your UI resources are still available to resume the activity quickly.

I am really interested in implementing a good memory management in my application so I am looking forward to implement the [onTrimMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) in the right way.

I only have a few questions about it:

- is [onTrimMemory(TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) called right after the onStop()?
- what "release your UI resources" means in that context? just for instance clean the Bitmap cache, or actually remove and destroy every View in the View tree? i usually destroy the Views in the *onDestroy()* or *onDestroyView()* methods, i am now wondering if i'm doing it right.
- is there a Twin/correspondent callback to [onTrimMemory(TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29)? like *onCreate-onDestroy*, *onStart-onStop*, *onCreateView-onDestroyView*. I'm asking to understand where and how i should restore the UI state after an Activity/Fragment as been brought in foreground after [onTrimMemory(TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) has been called.

Comment: Note that onTrimMemory(level) is called by the system on all Android components - not just Activity/Fragment.

Comment: see sample Implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28210326/185022

Answer (score 40, accepted):

- onTrimMemory with TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN level is actually called before onStop. When onStop is called, it means the activity is really stopping, and the Android OS might kill it right away if it needs to, so you should not expect any more calls to that activity's callbacks aftet that, except for onRestart and sometimes onDestroy.
- "release your UI resources" is actually about things like caches. You usually don't have to worry about managing views or UI components because the OS already does that, and that's why there are all those callbacks for creating, starting, pausing, stopping and destroying an activity. However, sometimes to improve performance you have to increase memory usage, such as caching some data used by your activities. That's the type of resource you should release when onTrimMemory is called, so your app uses less memory, even if it affects performance. You should worry about memory leaks though. If your activity stops, be sure not to keep any references to its views, because that would keep the activity from being garbage collected, which would keep the whole context from being collected, and that's bad, mostly if you want to keep your app running for hours or days (like when you implement services).
- No, there's no correspondent callback to onTrimMemory. However, you shouldn't need one. As I said before, if you keep a cache of some resources to improve performance, just empty that, and let it grow again if it needs to. If memory level keeps low, onTrimMemory may be called again soon, with that same memory level. By the way, keep in mind that onTrimMemory will be called with several different memory levels, not just TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN.

Comment: Can you explain that `If your activity stops, be sure not to keep any references to its views`?

Comment: I think he means that you shouldn't keep a static reference to the activity or to its views. Because if the system needs to kill that activity to reclaim memory, it won't be able to free all retained size because there is a static reference which its lifetime is longer than the lifetime of the activity. That's a memory leak.

Answer (score 29):

**Sample Implementation**

```
public class AppContext extends Application {
//This my introduce OutOfMemoryException if you don't handle register and removal quiet well, better to replace it with weak reference   
private static List<IMemoryInfo> memInfoList = new ArrayList<AppContext.IMemoryInfo>();

public static abstract interface IMemoryInfo {
        public void goodTimeToReleaseMemory();
    }

@Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
//don't compare with == as intermediate stages also can be reported, always better to check >= or <=
            if (level >= ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW) {
                try {
                // Activity at the front will get earliest than activity at the
                // back
                for (int i = memInfoList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    try {
                        memInfoList.get(i).goodTimeToReleaseMemory();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

/**
     * 
     * @param implementor
     *            interested listening in memory events
     */
    public static void registerMemoryListener(IMemoryInfo implementor) {
        memInfoList.add(implementor);
    }

    public static void unregisterMemoryListener(IMemoryInfo implementor) {
        memInfoList.remove(implementor);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ActivityParent extends Activity implements AppContext.IMemoryInfo {

    protected ActivityParent child;


@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            if (child != null)
                AppContext.unregisterMemoryListener(child);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ActivityChild extends ActivityParent {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        child = this;
    }

        /---move following onResume() in parent as following eg:
/*
*@Override
*       protected void onResume() {     
*           super.onResume();
*           if(null != child){
*           AppContext.registerMemoryListener(this);
*           }
*       }
*/
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {     
            super.onResume();
            AppContext.registerMemoryListener(this);
        }

@Override
public void goodTimeToReleaseMemory() { 
    super.goodTimeToReleaseMemory();
//remove your Cache etc here
}
//--NO Need because parent implementation will be called first, just for the sake of clarity 
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            if (null != child)
                AppContext.unregisterMemoryListener(child);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

**More Info:**

When your app is running:
*TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_MODERATE* 
The device is beginning to run low on memory. Your app is running and not killable.

*TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW* 
The device is running much lower on memory. Your app is running and not killable, but please release unused resources to improve system performance (which directly impacts your app's performance).

*TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL* 
The device is running extremely low on memory. Your app is not yet considered a killable process, but the system will begin killing background processes if apps do not release resources, so you should release non-critical resources now to prevent performance degradation.

When your app's visibility changes:
*TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN* 
Your app's UI is no longer visible, so this is a good time to release large resources that are used only by your UI.

When your app's process resides in the background LRU list:
*TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND* 
The system is running low on memory and your process is near the beginning of the `LRU` list. Although your app process is not at a high risk of being killed, the system may already be killing processes in the `LRU` list, so you should release resources that are easy to recover so your process will remain in the list and resume quickly when the user returns to your app.

*TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE* 
The system is running low on memory and your process is near the middle of the LRU list. If the system becomes further constrained for memory, there's a chance your process will be killed.

*TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE* 
The system is running low on memory and your process is one of the first to be killed if the system does not recover memory now. You should release absolutely everything that's not critical to resuming your app state.
To support API levels lower than 14, you can use the `onLowMemory()` method as a fallback that's roughly equivalent to the `TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE` level.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html

Comment: thanks for the explanation. If I use onTrimMemory(int level) in Activity, will it called automatically ?

Comment: @AkhileshMani yes its a callback, based on your apps usage you will get call back accordingly.

Comment: but how to free memory ? we get callbacks but after that what i should. Please if you can give me any example. how remove cache.

Answer (score 1):

I was forcing the problem that onTrimMemory() was never called when the display turned off.
Thus I tried a workaround using ActivityLifecycleCallbacks:
I used a simple counter:

```
onActivityStarted(){
    i++;
}

onActivityStopped(){
    i--;
    if(i==0) // no more open activities, thus screen probably turned off
}
```

It worked for me but im not sure if it is a safe way. RFC

UPDATE: Starting a camera intent, the application closed, too so it is not exactly behaving as desired.

Used this code instead. works just fine:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    BroadcastReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String strAction = intent.getAction();
            if (strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                // do sth
            }
        }
    };
    getApplicationContext()
            .registerReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver, theFilter);
}
```