# Best way to cache in memory a single Bitmap shared across instances

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

To draw my sprites in OpenGL i use a single backing bitmap across multiple objects, the Bitmap is reused if size is big enough or recreated if too small. Currently i am using a static Bitmap object but i think this is causing memory leaks even if i am not sure about that.

So, let's say i need a single Bitmap shared between multiple objects, what would be the best approach?

1) Use a single Bitmap as a static reference as i do

2) Use a static weakreference (even if its not suggested in the android dev page here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

3) Use a singleton and then a Bitmap inside it (but this would be like 1)

4) Use an LRU cache and just creating a new bitmap every time i need it to be bigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,3 & 4 are essentially all the same. You create a `static` reference to either your `Bitmap` directly or to something that holds a reference. The same happens when you use the `Application` class to "anchor" that bitmap. That class is kept by Android alive and is in this context the same as a `static` reference.

Whether this is a memory leak or not depends on your definition. Leaked objects are those that are kept safe from the garbage collector by *unintentional* references to them. So it's certainly not a leak while you want that reference to keep your bitmap.

The problem that arises with cached data that is independent of the life of some `Activity`, `Fragment` or in more general terms ["task"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) is that the data will keep memory occupied even if the user is never coming back to your app. The app process is kept alive until Android decides it needs the memory. That time between your last legit use of the bitmap and Android finally killing your app and thereby cleaning the memory can be seen as leak.

If we had magic powers, we could simply clean up the cache once we know that is going to happen. There are some realistic options though:

- Using Android's callbacks: [understanding onTrimMemory( int level )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398827/understading-ontrimmemory-int-level)
- time limits on references: e.g. https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap

2) is not an option. If you're trying to use `WeakReference` as cache, you haven't understood what that class is intended for and I honestly don't understand why it is even mentioned in the documentation (weakly referenced objects should be garbage collected as fast as possible once nobody has a strong reference anymore).

`SoftReference` is intended for "caching" but using it as actual cache is not only broken on Android. It's broken by design because you give the garbage collector the responsibility to maintain a cache for you without telling it how to prioritize objects or how much memory it should keep guaranteed under what conditions. The result is that the GC will clean up the wrong thing or simply everything. SoftReference can be used to in addition to a proper cache that knows how to clean up.

---

In addition to all of that: be aware that a single `Bitmap` may not be enough. If you had a look at [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) you may have noticed that 1 app process can have 2 or more independent tasks in parallel. That means there could be whatever Activity uses the bitmap in different stages. If you don't want to overwrite your cache bitmap between those all the time, you may have to have 1 bitmap per task.

I don't know how to do it per task, but you can easily use a retained fragment to tie the life of your bitmap to that of an activity (ignoring screen rotation etc): http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html / example with bitmap cache https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/util/BitmapCache.java

Comment: I am accessing the Bitmap from a service on a single thread not an Activity so i am safely using 1 single bitmap, investigating the issue further i found that the problem i had was in OpenGL rathen than the bitmap, its difficult to find because dumpmem shows it as "Other Dev", the hprof does not contain that reference and its also difficult to get from the heap. Anyway, i have solved that and now the option "1" works pretty well, i am recycling it during onTrimMemory. In any case i mark your answer as good because its relly helpful and also correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to create Singleton with hard reference plus some methods for recycling and loading, I've created a lot different way Bitmap and graphics loaders and this is probably most efficient and easiest for access way

```
public class BitmapLoader{

    public static BitmapLoader bl;
    private static Bitmap b=null;

    public static BitmapLoader getInstance(){
        if(bl==null)
            bl = new BitmapLoader();
        return bl;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(Context c){
        if(b==null && c!=null)
            b=loadBitmapUsingContectIfNeededOrWhateverYouWant(c);
        return b;
    }

    public void recycleBitmap(){ //for e.g. onDestroy() Activity or other
        if(b!=null)
            b.recycle();
    }

}
```

keeping loaded Bitmap in LruCache is also good idea

Comment: This is basically what i already do, except that i am not using a singleton but i dont think it will change things very much

Comment: you've asked for most convenient and efficient way to store bitmaps, so above singleton matches your criteria. don't forget to recycle Bitmap when you don't need it anymore and you shouldn't get any memory leaks (which in Java are very hard to create). 1. static is less convenient for sharing between objects, 2. weak ref should be ommited as you need this accross objects 3. and 4. might be used together as above. tutorial linked in your question is well written (as it's straight from Google :)

Comment: thanks but i don't like the singleton approach because it looks like it might generate leaks the same way as the static Bitmap does now