# Saving data during Service killing

Tags: android

I've got a Service, that starting with `BOOT_COMPLETED`. This Service periodicaly sends GPS data to the server. Sometimes OS kills this Service in the wake of memory, but `onDestroy()` method of Service didn't called. Where can i put some values for saving and restoring when my Service is restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple put: You can't with the regular service lifecycle events.

If the `onDestroy()` method is not called the system killed the process the hard way, without terminating it properly. As there is no event for that you have to use other callbacks to detect a possible kill situation.

The only possibility which could help is to listen to `onTrimMemeroy` or `onLowMemeroy` although these callbacks do not mean that your service will be killed it might help as an indicator when you should save your data.

More can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html

For reference, here is the lifecycle of a service if terminated properly:

[image: service lifecycle]

Answer (score 0):

You can ovveride the `onTrimMemeroy()` and `onLowMemeroy()` method to handle this problem, the detailed illustration about these two method that you can get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398827/understading-ontrimmemory-int-level)