# how do I override onTrimMemory in android

Tags: android, memory-management

The Application class in android provides the methods onTrimMemory and onLowMemory. I don't really understand them (of course other than the obvious linguistic meaning). How might I implement the method onTrimMemory? What does it mean to trim memory? I am obviously looking for detail technical answers. Beyond emptying caches (should I do that?), there seems to be something more specific meant by trimming. How is that done in android? Is it an OS thing? Is it a system level thing? Should I worry about it? I would really love to know how to override it.

Comment: Android Performance Patterns has a video on this topic: https://youtu.be/x8Hddx1eOZo?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398827/understading-ontrimmemory-int-level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does it mean to trim memory?

Let go of objects, so they can be garbage-collected.

> Beyond emptying caches (should I do that?)

Yes.

> there seems to be something more specific meant by trimming

Not really. Android is saying "hey, um, things are getting a big snug on system RAM, could you cut back" for lighter levels, and is saying "gee, this is a real nice process you got here — it would be a shame if we had to terminate it" for more severe cases.

Bear in mind that with Dalvik (and I assume ART), garbage collection can actually reduce your process' working set size (a.k.a., amount of system RAM you are using), and so by reducing your heap usage, you make it a bit less likely that Android will terminate your process while you are in the background.

> How is that done in android?

Let go of objects, so they can be garbage-collected. Mostly, this should refer to caches. Anything else, you should be letting go of as your app runs, based on business rules. So, for example, while you *could* terminate background threads in `onTrimMemory()` (and therefore let go of any objects only reachable via those threads), there are probably better/earlier points in time to terminate those threads, if they are not adding any value.

> Is it an OS thing?

I do not know what you consider an "OS thing" to be.

> Is it a system level thing?

I do not know what you consider an "system level thing" to be.

> Should I worry about it?

If you are manually maintaining a cache that might consume a lot of memory, ideally yes.

If you are using a third-party library that has a cache (such as an image-loading library), see whether they register for `onTrimMemory()` themselves. If not, you might see if the library has some API for you to tell it to reduce the cache, then call that yourself from `onTrimMemory()`.